# How can I increase the number of pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I want to increase the number of pods in kubernetes for which I'm trying with the following commands but which gives an error Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps  not found

```
kubectl scale deployment <pod> --replicas=4
```

Comment: any update on this srikant ? mark one as answer if your issues resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You to pass the deployment name which you want to scale

```
kubectl scale deployment <deployment name>  --replicas=4
```

**POD** name wont work.

[Read more here/Example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#scaling-a-deployment)

```
kubectl scale deployment/nginx-deployment --replicas=10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can increase/decrease the number of Pods in a deployment using:

```
# To kill all pods in a deployment
kubectl scale deploy <deployment-name> --replicas=0

# To set the number of pods
kubectl scale deploy <deployment-name> --replicas=3
```